# Proving bijectivity f: ℚ² → ℚ²

Tags: functions

This is what I have to proof bijectivity for:

> f: ℚ² → ℚ² : (x,y) ↦ (3x + y, x + 2y)

First I have to proof that the function is injective by doing:

> f(x,y) = f(x',y')

And that's where I have trouble. It's the tuple that confuses me. If it was for a 'simple' function I'd have no problem.

---

Also, the function should be surjective of what I am sure, but unsure about the way I need to show this. Would be an example like this enough?

> x = 1, y = 2
> f(1,2)= (3+2, 1+4)
> f(1,2) = (5,5)

If not, any hint on how to do it?

Comment: Alas, the $x=1, y=2$ example proves only that $(5,5)$ is in the range of $f$; to be surjective we need that *every* ordered pair is in the range of $f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove injectivity, begin with $f(x,y)=f(x',y')$.  Hence $(3x+y,x+2y)=(3x'+y',x'+2y')$, which gives the linear system $3x+y=3x'+y', x+2y=x'+2y'$.  Solve for $x,y$ in terms of $x', y'$, and you will find that $x=x', y=y'$.

To prove surjectivity, let $(a,b)\in\mathbb{Q}^2$.  We want to find $(x,y)$ such that $f(x,y)=(a,b)$.  Hence $(3x+y,x+2y)=(a,b)$, and we have the linear system $3x+y=a, x+2y=b$.  Solve for $x,y$ in terms of $a,b$ and you will have found the desired $(x,y)$.

Comment: I wasn't sure about the surjectivity thing, but now I am and solved it, thank you! Now I'll be taking a closer look at the injectivity thing.

Answer (score 1):

To prove injectivity, you need to show that if $3x+y=3x'+y'$ **and** $x+2y=x'+2y'$ then $x=x'$ and $y=y'$.

From $3x+y=3x'+y'$ we conclude that $6x+2y=6x'+2y'$. Then, using the fact that $x+2y=x'+2y'$ we conclude that $5x=5x'$, and therefore $x=x'$. It then follows  that $y=y'$.

For surjectivity, an example is not enough. We need to show that for **any** $(a,b)$, there is an $(x,y)$ such that $3x+y=a$ and $x+2y=b$. Solve this system of equations for $x$ and $y$. The first equation is equivalent to $6x+2y=2a$. Then from $x+2y=b$ we find that $x=\frac{2a-b}{5}$. The appropriate $y$ is now easily found.

**Remark:** The transformation that takes $(x,y)$ to $(3x+y,x+2y)$ can also be viewed geometrically, as a rotation followed a rescaling.

Comment: This made everything clear to me and showed me my second try for the surjectivity was right, thank you!